# Perl - Recursively Examining Directory Tree

Tags: perl, recursion, directory

My script is supposed to recursively examine the current directory of all contained directories and files. It is then supposed to output each file and the last date modified.

It seems to be working for some directories within the current, but not others. I am getting skewed results and have no idea where my logic failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Cwd;
use Time::Piece;

my $startdir = &cwd;
my @files;

sub treeExamine() {


    my $workdir = shift;
    chdir($workdir) or die "Can't change directory\n";
    opendir(DIR,".") or die "Can't open directory\n";
    my @names = readdir(DIR) or die "Can't read directory\n";
    closedir(DIR);

    foreach my $name(@names) {

        next if($name eq ".");
        next if($name eq "..");
        if(-f $name) {
            my $dmod = (stat $name)[9];
            my($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($dmod);

            $day = substr('0'.$mday,-2);
            $month = substr('0'.($mon+1),-2);
            $year = substr($year+1900,-2);

            push (@files, "$name\t Modified on : $day/$month/$year\n");
        }
        else {
            print "not file $name\n";
        }
        if(-d $name) {
            &treeExamine($name);
            next;
        }

        chdir($startdir) or die "Unable to change to directory $startdir \n";
    }

}

&treeExamine(".");
print @files;
```

Comment: Don't use empty parenthesis after sub name, that is a prototype, and you most likely don't want to use those. In this case, it forces you to use the `&` notation on the subroutine call to override the prototype. Also, you are trying to reinvent the wheel: [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) will allow you to traverse a directory recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For recursively traversing a directory tree, you should use [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aFind). It is a core module in Perl 5. Also, you can use [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece) to skip your awkward date manipulation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use File::Find;

find(\&wanted, ".");

sub wanted {
    return if -d;
    my $dmod = (stat $_)[9];
    my $t = localtime($dmod);
    print "$File::Find::name\t Modified on : ", $t->dmy("/"), "\n"; 
}
```

This code will (I assume) do what you intend for your code to do, namely scan the directories in the current directory `"."` and print modification dates for all the files. The predefined function `dmy` was not available with 2-digit years, but then, why create Y2K bugs if you don't have to? Imagine the date `11th Nov 2011`.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, you should not use [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes). They are optional, and their purpose is to allow extra functionality for subroutines, in order to emulate some of the behaviour of built-in commands (such as `map` and `grep` taking a code bracket without the `sub` keyword, or `pop`, `shift` etc. taking an array without it expanding into its elements). Your sub declaration should be

```
sub treeExamine {
```

And nothing else.